# Это: союз или частица?

Tags: части-речи

Как показывает форум, "это" вызывало тут уже вопросы. Вызвало и у меня, когда писала свой вопрос о тире перед "это". Просто не знала, как его назвать. Союз? Частица? Слово-связка?
Либо же оно может быть и тем, и другим, и третьим? И как корректнее всего будет назвать его в общем?

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, ...

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о "тире перед **это**", так *это* там будет **местоимением**. Вот что пишет МАС:

**ЭТОТ**, этого, м.; эта, этой, ж.; это, этого, ср.; мн. эти, этих; мест.

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
4. указательное, в знач. сущ. **это**, **этого**, ср. Употребляется для указания на действия, обстоятельства, события и т. д., о которых говорится в предшествующем или последующем предложениях. *Брови Лизы не то чтобы нахмурились, а дрогнули; это с ней всегда случалось, когда она слышала что-нибудь неприятное*. Тургенев, Дворянское гнездо. *Приезд Степана Астахова взволновал весь хутор: в каждом курене, на каждом гумне об этом только и говорили.* Шолохов, Тихий Дон. **| это, нескл., ср.** В качестве связки в составном сказуемом. - *Быть молодым и не уметь - это сносно; но состариться и не быть в силах - это тяжело.* Тургенев, Дворянское гнездо. **| это, нескл., ср.** В функции несогласованного подлежащего. - *Этот дом я знаю, - сказал я сам себе. - Это дом Зверкова.* Гоголь, Записки сумасшедшего. *Мать посмотрела на женщину - это была Самойлова, дальше сидел ее муж.* М. Горький, Мать. **|| это, этого, ср.** В сочетании со словом „всё“ указывает на перечисляемые предметы, выполняя функцию обобщающего слова. *Крик, шум, разнородные голоса и восклицания, звон железа, вой, блеянье, топот, ржание, хлопанье по рукам, и все это сливается в какой-то общий, нестройный гам.* Григорович, Антон-Горемыка.

Answer (score 1):

При грамматическом анализе для каждого слова нужно определить его морфологию и синтаксис: какая это часть речи и  какова роль этого слова в предложении. Для этого удобно пользоваться толковым словарем (например, на Грамоте.ру).

Часть речи:  1) склоняемое местоимение ЭТОТ, ЭТО - его форма. 2) Частица (указательно-выделительная): Кто это пришёл? Куда это ты идёшь? Ведь это я тебе звонил.

Член предложения:

1) На это я не согласен (дополнение). Это красиво (подлежащее).

2) слово-связка( при сказуемом, выраженном сущ., инф. или предикат. нареч.). Музыка - это блаженство. Руководить - это быть всегда впереди. Путешествие - это всегда интересно.

3) указательное слово в различных конструкциях: Рентген был известный физик, это он открыл гамма-излучение.  Экономический кризис - об этом пишут все газеты. Музыка, голоса - всё это сливается в общий шум. Пляж, море, танцы - это мне знакомо.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

У местоимения в этом случае есть красивое название: анафорический элемент, он отсылает нас назад, к предыдущему содержанию. Существуют также катафорические элементы (отсылающие читателя вниз-вперед): давайте сделаем так, я прошу вас об одном.